# With a double-entry Bulgarian visa, can we go to Romania first?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, romania, bulgaria

I am an Indian citizen with a double-entry Bulgarian visa. Our flight is from New Delhi to Bucharest, Romania. We will stay in Romania for 4 days and then go to  Bulgaria.

Does my double-entry Bulgarian visa allow me to first enter Romania, rather than  Bulgaria?

Answer (score 2):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=in&DE=ro&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a **C visa issued by
>   Bulgaria**, Croatia or Cyprus valid for the period of intended
>   stay. They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days.

So it only has to be valid on the day you enter Romania; there is **no** requirement that you enter Bulgaria first.

It is, however, likely that you will face check-in/gate staff not aware of this rule, who will try to refuse you boarding on the flight. If this happens, tell them to check Timatic, which says that a valid Bulgarian visa is valid for Romania.